# Matching multiple data in R taking into account the control variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

here mydata

```
mydatatr=structure(list(channel_id = c(1755L, 1755L), multifr_type = c(0L, 
0L), offer_category_id = c(718L, 718L), adapter_id = c(3L, 3L
), adapter_id2 = c(0L, 0L), airline1 = c(238L, 238L), airline2 = c(0L, 
0L), meta_ui_type = c(0L, 0L), offer_flight_type_category_id = c(1L, 
1L), discount_category_id = c(1L, 6L), flight_area = c(1L, 1L
), count_sessions = c(13297L, 12026L), count_orders = c(3264L, 
2400L), conversion = c(0.245, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

second dataset

```
mydatincom=structure(list(channel_id = c(1755L, 1755L, 1755L), multifr_type = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), offer_category_id = c(718L, 718L, 14L), adapter_id = c(3L, 
3L, 3L), adapter_id2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), airline1 = c(238L, 238L, 
13L), airline2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), meta_ui_type = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    offer_flight_type_category_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), discount_category_id = c(1L, 
    6L, 1L), flight_area = c(1L, 1L, 2L), count_sessions = c(13297L, 
    12026L, 0L), count_orders = c(3264L, 2400L, 0L), conversion = c(0.245, 
    0.2, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

here control dataset

```
    control_var=structure(list(offer_category_id = c(10L, 18L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 64L, 65L, 67L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

and last dataset

```
aggr=structure(list(channel_id = 1755L, multifr_type = 0L, adapter_id = 3L, 
    adapter_id2 = 0L, airline1 = 13L, airline2 = 0L, meta_ui_type = 0L, 
    offer_flight_type_category_id = 1L, discount_category_id = 1L, 
    flight_area = 2L, count_sessions = 562L, count_orders = 22L, 
    conversion = structure(1L, .Label = "0.039", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

i need join `mydatatr` with `mydaticnom` by these variables `channel_id+multifr_type+adapter_id+adapter_id2+airline1+airline2+meta_ui_type+offer_flight_type_category_id+discount_category_id+flight_area`, but with condition:

If, when joining these datasets in `mydatincom`, there is value of `offer_category_id`, but this value is not in the `control_var` data,
then we are looking for the variables `channel_id + multifr_type + adapter_id + adapter_id2 + airline1 + airline2 + meta_ui_type + offer_flight_type_category_id + discount_category_id + flight_area` in the `aggr` dataset, and if this values  are matched in `aggr` we join `aggr` and `mydatincom`  and take the fields `count_sessions + count_orders+conversion` into new data from `aggr`.

To be more clear let's see particular example.
For example, in `mydatincom` there is `offer_category_id` which not in `control_var`(value=14),
but the variables for the join ar`e channel_id + multifr_type + adapter_id + adapter_id2 + airline1 + airline2 + meta_ui_type + offer_flight_type_category_id + discount_category_id + flight`
which have the same values like in `mydatincom`,  there are in the `aggr`. So take from `aggr` `count_sessions + count_orders + conversio`n .

```
count_sessions count_orders conversion
562                22           0.039
```

and put it in the final dataset, and replce 14 value, by put `other`
so the result will look like this

```
desired_result=structure(list(channel_id = c(1755L, 1755L, 1755L), multifr_type = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), offer_category_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("718", 
"other"), class = "factor"), adapter_id = c(3L, 3L, 3L), adapter_id2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), airline1 = c(238L, 238L, 13L), airline2 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L), meta_ui_type = c(0L, 0L, 0L), offer_flight_type_category_id = c(1L, 
1L, 1L), discount_category_id = c(1L, 6L, 1L), flight_area = c(1L, 
1L, 2L), count_sessions = c(13297L, 12026L, 562L), count_orders = c(3264L, 
2400L, 22L), conversion = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0,2", 
"0,245", "0.039"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

  channel_id multifr_type offer_category_id adapter_id adapter_id2 airline1 airline2 meta_ui_type
1       1755            0               718          3           0      238        0            0
2       1755            0               718          3           0      238        0            0
3       1755            0             other          3           0       13        0            0
  offer_flight_type_category_id discount_category_id flight_area count_sessions count_orders
1                             1                    1           1          13297         3264
2                             1                    6           1          12026         2400
3                             1                    1           2            562           22
  conversion
1      0,245
2        0,2
3      0.039
```

How can i do it such matching?

Comment: The value 718 from `offer_category_id` also isn't in `control_var` correct? so your actual desired output should've had applied the extra step to the 1st and 2nd row, or did i got ir wrong?

Also, let me say what i got from your text and you say if its correct: if `offer_category_id` is in `control_var`, we just `rbind(mydatatr, mydatincom)`, else we `rbind(mydatatr, aggr)` - as only the last three columns change, which is what you want - and change the `offer_category_id` to `"other"`.

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, what about 718 it is correct , cause it in mydatatr.
or did i got ir wrong?  you are right. and you did right understand my text!

Comment: I need to analyze every row of `mydatincom`, and the first has `718` for `offer_category_id`. This number isn't present in `control_var`, so that's a reason to make that transformation. But, what you're saying is that as `718` is present in the values that are already in `mydatatr`, i don't do the transformation, correct? Or i don't put that row in the new data frame at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what i commented, but ignoring the cases that are already in `mydatatr`. As we are ignoring rows from `mydatatr`, but we don't want to do the same for `aggr` - and the loop index `i` keeps counting up - i placed the index `i-k`, which will increase only when a row from `aggr` is used.

```
k=0
for(i in 1:nrow(mydatincom)){
  
  if(! mydatincom$offer_category_id[i] %in% mydatatr$offer_category_id){
  #If the value isn't already in mydatatr
    
    if(! mydatincom$offer_category_id[i] %in% control_var){
      #If the value isn't in the control var
      newrow = tibble::add_column(aggr[i-k,], "other", .after="multifr_type")
      colnames(newrow) = colnames(mydatatr)
      mydatatr = rbind(mydatatr, newrow)}
    
    else{
      mydatatr = rbind(mydatatr, mydatincom[i,])}}
  else{k=k+1}} #Count the numbers of ignored cases from the 1st "if"
```